# Error when installing cocoapods

Tags: ruby, terminal, cocoapods, osx-yosemite

I was using cocapods until update my mac OSX 10.10.. 
I tried install again but I was getting error

```
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -rubygems /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-0.9.6/bin/rake RUBYARCHDIR=/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/xcodeproj-0.17.0 RUBYLIBDIR=/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/xcodeproj-0.17.0
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for -std=c99 option to compiler... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:549:in `block in try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:502:in `with_werror'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:549:in `try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:24:in `block in <main>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:895:in `block in checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:894:in `checking_for'
    from extconf.rb:23:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/...]
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/ext/xcodeproj/Rakefile:37:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => default => ext
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/xcodeproj-0.17.0/gem_make.out
```

Comment: `You have to install development tools first.`

Comment: which one ? because there is a lot of (210). or how can back to my older system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this (Worked for me with OSX 10.10)

1. Open Xcode 6
2. Open Preferences
3. Click the Locations tab
4. Change the Command line tools version to Xcode 6.0
5. Uninstall Cocoapods

   $ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
6. Install xcodeproj

   $ sudo gem install xcodeproj
7. Install Cocoapods

   $ sudo gem install cocoapods

Run `pod --version` to verify

Comment: when I run
 $sudo gem install xcodeproj...


ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'xcodeproj' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: ok, so first install homebrew. put this in your terminal: ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)" or copy it from this site:http://brew.sh/ its at the bottom